# Cannot import Tensorflow v1.12

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I've installed Tensorflow 1.12 on Python 3.6.7 using:

```
conda install tensorflow-gpu
```

Running Windows Server 2016 with an CPU that supports AVX and AVX2. I
get the following when importing tensorflow:

```
 import tensorflow as tf
```

> ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call
>   last)
>   ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py
>   in 
>        57 
>   ---> 58   from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
>        59   from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import **version**
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py
>   in 
>        27             return _mod
>   ---> 28     _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
>        29     del swig_import_helper
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py
>   in swig_import_helper()
>        23             try:
>   ---> 24                 _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname,
>   description)
>        25             finally:
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py in load_module(name, file, filename, details)
>       242         else:
>   --> 243             return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
>       244     elif type_ == PKG_DIRECTORY:
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py in load_dynamic(name, path, file)
>       342             name=name, loader=loader, origin=path)
>   --> 343         return _load(spec)
>       344
>
> ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>   ----> 1 import tensorflow as tf
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow__init__.py in 
>        22 
>        23 # pylint: disable=g-bad-import-order
>   ---> 24 from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
>        25 
>        26 try:
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python__init__.py in
>   
>        47 import numpy as np
>        48 
>   ---> 49 from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
>        50 
>        51 from tensorflow.python.tools import component_api_helper
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py
>   in 
>        72 for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
>        73 above this error message when asking for help.""" % traceback.format_exc()
>   ---> 74   raise ImportError(msg)
>        75 
>        76 # pylint: enable=wildcard-import,g-import-not-at-top,unused-import,line-too-long
>
> ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\tkassis\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py",
>   line 58, in 
>       from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *   File "C:\Users\tkassis\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py",
>   line 28, in 
>       _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()   File "C:\Users\tkassis\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py",
>   line 24, in swig_import_helper
>       _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)   File "C:\Users\tkassis\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py",
>   line 243, in load_module
>       return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)   File "C:\Users\tkassis\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
>       return _load(spec) ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.